# Spring IoC - Dependency Injection -> NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have this structure:

An interface IProjectService and this is implemented by ProjectServiceImpl.

Now I have a controller in which I want to use the Dependency Injection:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/testFolder")
public class MyDIController {
    ...
    private IProjectService projectServiceImpl;

    public void setProjectServiceImpl(IProjectService projectServiceImpl) {
        this.projectServiceImpl= projectServiceImpl;
    }
    ...
    @RequestMapping(value="/project", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Project getProject() {
        Project project = this.projectServiceImpl.getProject(12); // line 37! (id 12 is a test case, it does exist, here is he error: this.projectServiceImpl = null)
        return project;
    }
}
```

In my applicationContext.xml I have these lines of code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
    <bean id="projectServiceImpl" class="com.mydomain.project.service.impl.ProjectServiceImpl" />
    <bean id="projectService" class="com.mydomain.project.service.IProjectService">
        <property name="projectServiceImpl">
            <ref local="projectServiceImpl"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

But if I run my application I get an error (NullPointerException) in my MyDIController in this line of code:

```
... = this.projectServiceImpl.getProject(12);
```

The problem is, that

```
this.projectServiceImpl
```

is null and so it seems that the Dependency Injection does not work.

What's wrong here, does anyone know?

Best Regards Tim.

Update:

Full Error Trace:

```
09.12.2010 11:16:53 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SCHWERWIEGEND: Servlet.service() for servlet project threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mydomain.project.controller.MyDIController.getAllProjects(MyDIController.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:195)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:159)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:141)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:90)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:417)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
09.12.2010 11:16:53 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SCHWERWIEGEND: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mydomain.project.controller.MyDIController.getProject(MyDIController.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:195)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:159)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:141)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:90)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:417)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

`

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
    <bean id="projectService" class="com.mydomain.project.service.impl.ProjectServiceImpl" />

    <bean id="myDIController" class="com.mydomain.project.controller.MyDIController">
        <property name="projectServiceImpl">
            <ref local="projectService"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml:

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>project</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

app-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mydomain.project" />

    <!-- Application Message Bundle -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages/messages" />
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Configures Spring MVC -->
    <import resource="mvc-config.xml" />
</beans>
```

Comment: how do you obtain the instance of your controller?

Comment: tiny variable naming tip: don't name variables that have an interface type with *Impl...it's a granted fact that your using an implementation

Comment: @Liviu T.: okay, I will change this after this problem is solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven;t injected property `projectServiceImpl` for `MyDIController`

Conf. should be like

```
<bean id="projectService" class="com.mydomain.project.service.impl.ProjectServiceImpl" />

<bean id="myDIController " class="com.mydomain.project.service.MyDIController">
        <property name="projectServiceImpl">
            <ref local="projectService"/>
        </property>
</bean>
```

in web.xml

```
<web-app>
     <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/application-context.xml                     
            </param-value>
        </context-param>
.
.
.
.
<servlet>
.
.
.
```

Comment: @Bozho he haven't injected service in controller, also service should refer to its impl in context

Comment: ah, yes.. he hasn't even mapped the controller.

Comment: I still get the same error: Servlet.service() for servlet project threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException in the line of = this.projectServiceImpl.getProject(12);

Comment: @Tim how you get an instance of myDIController?

Comment: Yes, I used this conf. it does not work. In my initial post, there is now the full trace.

Comment: @Tim I can;t see any full conf. and stacktrace updated in your Question. you can edit your Question and update it

Comment: @Tim please update it in your question only, it would be readable.

Comment: All updated. The new applicationContext is in it and the stacktrace.

Comment: @Tim one more thing your controller class's code and how do you instantiate it ?

Comment: This is done with Spring MVC: I call a URL localhost:8080/myproject/testFolder and this is annotated: @Controller @RequestMapping(value="/testFolder") public class MyDIController {...}

Comment: @Tim I can't see line no 37 in your updated Question. I want to know what is null exactly it is service only or anything other than that

Comment: one more time updated, my debugger tells me, that this.projectServiceImpl = null, so it seems the injection does not work. How can I check that the applicationContext.xml will be read? Or what other possibilities do I have?

Comment: @Tim it seems container is not reading your application-context.xml , as you previously you created interface bean , it won't allow it. but it didn;t show you any error , anyways got the problem check my update in answer :)

Comment: I updated my question, in my web.xml, there is already a contextConfigLocation.

Comment: @Tim put it directly under`<web-app >` instead in servlet

Comment: I put the beans from applicationContext.xml to app-config.xml and it works! Is this what you mean with "put it directly under`<web-app >` instead in servlet"?

Comment: @Tim it will work with this way because now your container is reading beans from app-context, but better thing is to do it like service beans should be in another context file and controllers are in different and you should import service beans in controller's xml file using `<import resource="file name.xml">` , cheers :)

Comment: @Tim don;t you think I now deserve this question as marked with a upvote :p  ??

Comment: @Tim it was nice conversation :)

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options.

1. Declare an XML Bean for your controller and set the property for your service in that.
2. Depending on your version of Spring, use Spring's Annotation/Autowiring support.

If you choose number 2, be sure to include `<context:component-scan base-package="com.your.package"/>` in your xml configuration and mark your controller class with @Controller and @Autowired for your projectService property.